# How to Fill a rectangle with color every time the user clicks it? pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I know that there are several similar questions online, but none of them really helped me. I simply want to draw a grid and give the user the option to click into those grid cells. Every time the user clicks, the color/fill of the cell should change from black to white.
What I'm doing at the moment is the following:

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (200, 200, 200)

def drawGrid(h, w, blocksize):
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blocksize, y*blocksize,
                               blocksize, blocksize)
            pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, rect, 1)


def handle_events():
    col = WHITE

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                col = WHITE
                # determine mouse position
                mpos_x, mpos_y = event.pos
                # determine cell number
                coord = mpos_x // blocksize, mpos_y // blocksize

                rect = pygame.Rect(coord[0]*blocksize, coord[1]*blocksize, 
                                    blocksize, blocksize)
                pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, col, rect, 1)
            pygame.display.update()

def main():

    global SCREEN, CLOCK, blocksize

    w = int( sys.argv[1] )
    h = int( sys.argv[2] )
    blocksize = int( sys.argv[3] )

    pygame.init()
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((h, w))
    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    
    drawGrid(h,w,blocksize)
    handle_events()
    
        


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

The program is printing the grid. However, when I click somewhere nothing happens. I know this is not the best code, so I would appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you want the cell colour to be permanently changed or only while the mouse button is pressed?

Comment: I'd say permanently. Because what I want to do in the end is implement the rules of the game of life and at least then the colours will change in every iteration. I'm still not quite sure how to do that, but a nice inital grid would be a good start I thought

Comment: You should probably start by creating a 2-dimensional list for your cells, these can hold their current state (colour). Then your `drawGrid` function would iterate over this array of cells and draw them in their current colour and your click handler would just change the clicked on cell's colour

Answer (score 3):

I changed the code a little and it worked properly, `pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, col, rect, 1)` you draw same thing and you can't see the change. You should use `pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, col, rect)`:

```
import pygame
import sys

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (200, 200, 200)
# WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
# WINDOW_WIDTH = 400


def drawGrid(h, w, blocksize):
    #blockSize = 20 #Set the size of the grid block
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*blocksize, y*blocksize,
                               blocksize, blocksize)
            pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, rect, 1)


def handle_events():
    #coords_list = []
    col = WHITE

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                col = WHITE
                # determine mouse position
                mpos_x, mpos_y = event.pos
                # determine cell number
                coord = mpos_x // 32, mpos_y // 32

                rect = pygame.Rect(coord[0]*32, coord[1]*32, 
                                    32, 32)
                pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, col, rect)
                #coords_list.append(coord)

            pygame.display.update()         

    #return coords_list

def main():

    global SCREEN, CLOCK, blocksize



    pygame.init()
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 640))
    CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    
    drawGrid(480,640,32)
    handle_events()
    
        


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

As a suggestion, I think you should use sprite for every cell. For example like this:

```py
class Cell(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, sprite_group, x, y, cell_dimension, color=BLACK):
        self.groups = sprite_group
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((cell_dimension, cell_dimension))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x * cell_dimension
        self.rect.y = y * cell_dimension
        
        self.clicked = False
    
    def update(self):
        if self.clicked:
            self.image.fill(WHITE)
```